# Can a proto3 optional field be changed to repeated without breaking wire compatibility?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto3

Let's say that I have a proto3 message defined as follows, for use as a gRPC request (i.e. using protobuf's binary encoding):

```
message MyRequest {
  string name = 1;
}
```

Can I change my server (i.e. the reader of the message) to use the following definition without breaking wire compatibility for existing clients (i.e. writers)?

```
message MyRequest {
  repeated string names = 1;
}
```

In the [proto2 language guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto), I see the following:

> `optional` is compatible with `repeated`. Given serialized data of a repeated field as input, clients that expect this field to be `optional` will take the last input value if it's a primitive type field or merge all input elements if it's a message type field.

However, the proto3 documentation does not contain an equivalent statement. I think that this may be related to the use of the `packed` encoding for repeated fields in proto3.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is possible as the binary encoding for an optional `string` and for a `repeated string` with a single element are the same. However, this change may be confusing to readers of the code because it is not immediately obvious that a message can be reinterpreted in this way.

Comment: Hi, i was wondering if a repeated field can be changed to optional (which is default for proto3) without breaking compatability, the language guide only give a example of client expect optional can parse repeated field correctly, but doesn't mention if it's also compatible for client expect repeated but get optional field.